# Angular/cli, how to load html files with custom extension or file type

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In my angular 2 project, I use templates separately and load using templateUrl property. The file type or extension of template file is not html instead it is something like "app.component.jkhtml". While trying to load build app using ng serve, compilation fails and error is shown saying, please use appropriate loader to the file type. 
I am not able to compile application nor I am able to make template inline with angular/cli.
Can anyone advise?

Comment: Can you please explain why the extension is not html as it should be?

Comment: You can use own Webpack configuration instead ng-cli for using another file types: `ng eject` (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject)

Comment: @DanR. This is something related to project arch, which I cannot share. Sorry for that :)

Comment: @raciasolvo . As of now I used gulp to make template inline and then use cli to compile. It seems to work fine. I'll try your sugestion. Thanks :)